# How can I optimize this code - Spotify ad muter

Tags: python, optimization, spotify

I wrote a code to use with Spotify free that mutes ads automatically, how can I optimize this so it doesn't use a lot of resources/battery on a laptop?
The code used to break and give an error when I pause spotify, so I put that weird try/except pass line, but there's probably a better way. Thanks for any help!

```
import time
from SwSpotify import spotify
import pyautogui
ad = False
while not ad:
    try:
        if spotify.song() == "Advertisement":
            ad = True
            pyautogui.press("volumemute")
        while ad:
            if spotify.song() != "Advertisement":
                pyautogui.press("volumemute")
                ad = False
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
```

The error I get without using try/except:

```
C:\Users\ComputerShop\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\SwSpotify\web_server.py:48: UserWarning: The 'environ['werkzeug.server.shutdown']' function is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 2.1.
  func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ComputerShop\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\SwSpotify\spotify.py", line 139, in current
    return get_info_web()
  File "C:\Users\ComputerShop\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\SwSpotify\spotify.py", line 122, in get_info_web
    raise SpotifyClosed
SwSpotify.SpotifyClosed: Spotify appears to be closed at the moment.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ComputerShop/Desktop/spotifyskip.py", line 7, in <module>
    if spotify.song() == "Advertisement":
  File "C:\Users\ComputerShop\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\SwSpotify\spotify.py", line 149, in song
    return current()[0]
  File "C:\Users\ComputerShop\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\SwSpotify\spotify.py", line 141, in current
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\ComputerShop\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\SwSpotify\spotify.py", line 132, in current
    return get_info_windows()
  File "C:\Users\ComputerShop\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\SwSpotify\spotify.py", line 45, in get_info_windows
    raise SpotifyPaused
SwSpotify.SpotifyPaused: Spotify appears to be paused at the moment.
```

Comment: you could use `sleep` also inside `while ad` to use less CPU/Battery. You should check if spotify has some function to inform when song changed and if it can assing callback function.

Comment: better in question (not in comment) show error which you get.

Comment: Thanks! I also posted the error.